# How can I fix the keyboard shortcuts in the MariaDB/MySQL shell?

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb

I upgraded from Debian 10 to 11, and from MariaDB 10.3 to 10.7, and keyboard shortcuts were broken, due to a switch from GNU readline to the editline library.  I was used to using vi mode, but it is no longer supported, and standard emacs shortcuts also fail.

I haven't found any guides to rebuilding the mariadb client from source with the lost functionality restored, and I don't think it's worth trying to tackle on my own.

Any way to get back to a usable MariaDB/MySQL shell?

Answer (score 0):

I found a command line interface in python that works great: https://www.mycli.net

It has an option to set the default key bindings to either `vi` or `emacs`, along with other great features, including syntax highlighting and auto-completion.